# Using strings vs types in library api

Tags: c#, .net, api, design-patterns

I am designing a library that I expect others to consume in which "things" in the system can have arbitrary attributes assigned to them dynamically at runtime. In my case an `Attribute` is a class that has a delegate function that returns a float value given some input (not a C# language attribute). Each of these "things" has some methods for getting and setting these attributes. Internally each thing stores attributes in a `Dictionary` but I do not want to expose direct access to this dictionary to the api consumer because the set/get methods will also do things like emit events.

I'm having an arguement with myself about how these attributes should be accessed. My first thought was to just keep it simple and use strings, so a get method might be `thing.GetAttribute("Height")`. But I don't like this for a few reasons: 1.) it is easy to misspell the string name. 2.) This isnt type safe, things can only have 1 attribute of a given 'type' at a time. So my next thought was to use generics to remove the dangers of loose strings. The v2 api might look like this: `thing.GetAttribute<Height>()`.

The downside of that obviously is that classes need to be declared for each attribute type, but there is almost never any difference between the attribute implementations so requiring classes to be declared per attribute that needs to be added seems annoying. (Though code generation with a UI is very much on the table for this). If the classes were all pre-declared I would much prefer the generic solution here.

A more complete example:

```
var flower = new Item();
flower.SetAttribute<Petals>(4f);
float petalCount= flower.GetAttribute<Petals>(); //4
flower.GetAttribute<Gears>(); //0, flower doesnt have a Gears attribute
```

vs

```
var flower = new Item();
flower.SetAttribute("Petals", 4f);
float petalCount= flower.GetAttribute("Petals"); //4
flower.GetAttribute("Gears"); //0, flower doesnt have a Gears attribute
```

Ignoring the fact that this is a fairly contrived example and the system and reasons for this Get/Set api isnt fully explained, which is the perferred api design? Is there another pattern that might work that I haven't thought of here?

Comment: The good thing about generics is that they increase compile time type safety. The bad thing is that types need to be known at compile time and they are not known for many scenarios. Would I want to read user input (may be from an xml file) and dynamically create an item with some attributes? If so, generics make this kind of painful. Can I dynamically define new attributes? The question is how dynamic the attributes and their definitions are.

Comment: Good point about generating attributes at runtime. I don't think I'll need to do this but removing the options seems a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the classes you declare don't really correspond to the attribute type (they are all floats), the Generic version is really a weird api.  You would be better off with the string version, but put all the string as const fields in a class somewhere so they are not magic strings.

You could also just use a Dictionary.

You might also want to look at ExpandoObject and the dynamic keyword.

Comment: I didn't know about the dynamic keyword, thats pretty cool! I think you're right about the weirdness, I'll go with the const string solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a class derived from the dictionary class:

```
public class Item : Dictionary<Type. float>
{
    public float this[Type index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (ContainsKey(index)
                return base[index];
            return 0f;
        }
        set
        {
            Add(index, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
var flower = new Item();
flower[typeof(Petals)] = 4f;
float petalCount = flower[typeof(Petals)]; //4
flower[typeof(Gears)]; //0, flower doesnt have a Gears attribute
```